# Android Sql rawquery

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I need some help regarding the SQL raqQuery() method.
Can I pass a string array directly to it like I am doing in the below code?
I want to pass multiple ids to the DB and return a list of matching products to load the adapter from it.

```
public datatype foo(String[] ids){

Cursor cursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_product" + " WHERE productId" + "=?", ids);

}
```

Comment: @DerGol...lum can you explain more please, I am passing multiple ids because I want to return the data only of those ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The correct syntax is indeed something like

```
"SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE productId IN (?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

Simply put those ids you want to search among in your ids string array.
Depending on how many ids you put in the array, put the corresponding number of placeholders (**?**) in the query I suggested.

Done